# No puedo crear google sheets en una carpeta especifica

Tags: python-3.x, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-drive

Estoy intentando crear una gsheet en un directorio específico pero no para de darme errores o generarme la gsheet en mi carpeta "My Drive"

```
gc = gspread.authorize(GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())
  folder_id = "XXXXXX"
  body = {
        'name': nombre_gsheet,
        "parents": {"id":folder_id}
    }
  sh = gc.create(body)
  worksheet = gc.open(nombre_gsheet).sheet1
```

en la documentacion indica que puedes especificar el folder id, sin embargo al declarar la funcion como
`sh = gc.create("prueba",folder_id)`

indica:

`TypeError: create() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

traza completa del error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-c3ebfcbe7f1f> in <module>()
      1 d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
      2 df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
----> 3 exportar_resultados_drive('/content/drive/...',"prueba",df)

<ipython-input-2-d31153b2afc1> in exportar_resultados_drive(ruta, nombre_gsheet, df)
     59         "parents": {"id":folder_id}
     60     }
---> 61   sh = gc.create(nombre_gsheet,folder_id)
     62   worksheet = gc.open(nombre_gsheet).sheet1
     63 

TypeError: create() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: Puedes poner la traza de error completa por favor.

Comment: Acabo de añadir la traza completa del error